# Get only file name from openfiledialog

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filenames, openfiledialog

I have 2 forms,form 2 has a DataGridView and a label.The datagridview loads data from `My.Settings.Sourcename` and the label shows `My.Settings.Sourcename` value.

Now form 1 has a button and openfiledialog. On `OpenFileDialog.Dialogresult.OK`,the file name gets added to `My.Settings.Sourcename` and then shows form 2. And what form 2 does is already mentioned above.

Now,i can do this :

```
My.Settings.sourcename = Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
```

or

```
My.Settings.sourcename = OpenFileDialog1.SafeFileName
```

But if i do so, `My.Settings.Sourcename` value becomes only the file's name, not the destination. As a result my DataGridview on form 2 fails to load data from `My.Settings.Sourcename`. Now to fix this i can do this :

```
My.Settings.sourcename = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
```

But then the label(form2's)'s text shows the filename along with the filepath.. Is there any way to remove the file path from the label ?

Comment: I studied that already but can't seem to find how to trim everything except the file name(while displaying as a text in label)...

Comment: It's not a duplicate.My situation is different.

Comment: i know hot to get only the file name, but as mentioned in the question, i can't do so because then my 'datagridview' fails to load data

Comment: Pass the full path name to the form; store it as a local variable (is there only one?).  The form can trim and trim and chop it up and transform it as needed and still have the original data.  Using  Settings as global variables is a bit grody.

Comment: **This may not be a perfect solution but it'll get the job done**
A file name with a path might look like this _C:\abc\abc.txt_.If so then keep you code : **My.Settings.Sourcename=openfiledialog1.filename**.Now go to form to and declare to variables as string , for example _ab_ and _cd_.Now use the follwing code 

    `Dim ab as string=my.settings.sourcename`
    `Dim bc as string=ab.split("\").last`
    `Label1.text=bc`

What **split("\").last** will do is it will remove everything before "\" and only keep what's after "\".Hope it helps...

Comment: IT WORKED!IT WORKED! IT WORKED. You are a genius.........Thanks @AousafRashid